# Child theme stopped working

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I have been working on a website http://pacificexpress.com.au using the twenty twelve theme.

I was modifying the footer.php and when i refreshed my website  all the extra css  in the child theme was not working.

I reverted the changes i had made to the footer.php but nothing in my child theme css is being applied to my website. I also tried removing child theme all together then reinstalling but that did not work either.

any help will be appreciated,

James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure /twentytwelve/style.css file is also reverted back.
Also make sure in your footer.php you are directing it to use that css file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">
```